Cargo registry auth: Unable to login/publish to private cargo repo in JFrog Artifactory
I'm trying to publish a cargo pkg to federated cargo repository configured in Jfrog artifactory using cargo cli.
I get a 401 when I try to publish via cargo publish command from my local machine
`error: failed to publish to registry at https://<ARTIFACTORY_URL>>/artifactory/api/cargo/cargo-repo

Caused by: failed to get a 200 OK response, got 401
headers:HTTP/2 401
date: Wed, 11 Nov 2024 20:41:49 GMT
content-type: application/json
x-artifactory-trace-id:
x-jfrog-version:
x-artifactory-id:
x-artifactory-node-id:

body:Unauthorized user`

Here's my config.toml
[registry]
default = "artifactory"
global-credential-providers = ["cargo:token"]

[registries.artifactory] 
index = "sparse+https://<ARTIFACTORY_URL>/artifactory/api/cargo/cargo-repo-name/index/"

I have saved the Artifactory token in $HOME/.cargo/credentials.toml in following format
[registries.artifactory] token = "Bearer <TOKEN>
Followed various cargo/jfrog docs but couldn't find anything helpful. Running out of ideas on what am I missing here. Appreciate any insights.

Fixed. Cargo expects the crates to be uploaded under /crates directory in your repository. The issue was "include pattern" for permission target of my user in Artifactory. Setting it to crates/** worked.
